# Drop down list not displaying properly in fancybox

Tags: iframe, drop-down-menu, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox plugin in the website for displaying the country selection options to the user. So, I have a dropdown on my fancybox page that displays the list of country user can select and button "Go" which closes the fancybox and reloads the parent window. Also, I am replacing the normal dropdown `<select>` tag with the `<div>`'s to add style on the dropdown button. This is done using custom jscript similar to what's explained on the below [dropdown style](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)

To call this dropdown page, I am using

```
   $('a.fancy').fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    'scrolling': "no", 
    'width': 395, 
    'height': 123, 
    'overlayOpacity': 0.62,
    'onClosed': function () {
        parent.location.reload(true);
        ; // <---i guess you don't need this (JFK)
     }
    });
```

if I change the type to "`ajax`" my drop-down on the page shows fine with all the values. But when I use type as "`iframe`", my drop-down list values are not displaying outside the page and got truncated with the iframe window size (i.e first two values are visible and rest are not displayed outside of iframe window size)

Can anyone please suggest what's the difference it is causing when i am changing type from `ajax` to `iframe`?

Thanks!!
Yatish

Answer (score 1):

Kindly visit the codes in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ff2P9/

and tell me if this is the effect you want.

Basically, when you use `**type: iframe**` in conjunction with `**scrolling: no**`, any content outside the iframe's borders are **clipped** [*hidden from view*]. So, if you require to see the rest of the content [in an iframe], you need to set the *scrolling* option to either "**yes**" or "**auto**".

### snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.fancy').fancybox({
        'type': 'iframe',
        'scrolling': "auto", 
        'width': 395, 
        'height': 323, 
        'overlayOpacity': 0.62,
        'onClosed': function () {
            parent.location.reload(true);
            ; // <---i guess you don't need this (JFK)
         }
    });
    return false;
});
```

--

Again, please see fancybox in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ff2P9/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My customer has asked that scroll bar should not come on the iframe instead the drop-down list should cross the iframe's border and shows the complete list values. This behaviour is working on when i set type as 'ajax' but not when type is 'iframe' :(. In your example also, if you set scrolling to 'no', list shows value till "Japan" and rest of the values are not displayed. My client requirement is that these values should also appear even if they cross the iframe border

Comment: Yes, you will get the same behaviour when using an iframe, because everything loaded inside a frame is local to that window, it will never cross the borders, and since you declared the scrolling to "NO" then the effect you get is a "clipped" listing. Again, it's a normal behaviour when using frames.

Comment: oh!!..but this will not meet my requirement. Is there any other workaround that you can suggest? Otherwise I can change the call type to 'ajax' but the problem i am having with 'ajax' type is that on click on button i need to do server processing and close the fancybox and reload the parent. This i am able to achieve through 'iframe' call but not through the 'ajax' call

Comment: You have two options, 'ajax' or 'inline'. The iframe type is definitely not a choice for your requirement.

Comment: If I select 'ajax', is there a way on button "click", I can do server processing and close the fancybox and reload the parent?. For type 'iframe', i was calling server fn and in the server side doing below  string script = "parent.$.fancybox.close() ;"; 
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                   typeof(Page),
                   "close",
                   string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script>", script));  It was closing the fancybox and reloading the parent page. But this doesn't seems to be working with ajax call

Comment: To close fancybox declared as _type: ajax_, use `$.fancybox.close()`. You only use the `parent.$.fancybox.close()` when using _type: iframe_.

Comment: I will try to do more debug at my end. But I tried $.fancybox.close() from server code but it didn't help. It reload the same fancybox in full screen mode.